# How do I make my image from my django model to show in my HTML?

Tags: html, django, image, django-models, django-views

Need some help here. I want the image to show in the "card_img"-class, but nothing is showing.
I've got this HTML code:

```
    <section class="cards">
        {% for recipe in recipes %}
        {% if recipe.category == 'drink' %}
        <article class="card card--1">
            <div class="card__info-hover">
                <svg class="card__like" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path fill="#000000"
                        d="M12.1,18.55L12,18.65L11.89,18.55C7.14,14.24 4,11.39 4,8.5C4,6.5 5.5,5 7.5,5C9.04,5 10.54,6 11.07,7.36H12.93C13.46,6 14.96,5 16.5,5C18.5,5 20,6.5 20,8.5C20,11.39 16.86,14.24 12.1,18.55M16.5,3C14.76,3 13.09,3.81 12,5.08C10.91,3.81 9.24,3 7.5,3C4.42,3 2,5.41 2,8.5C2,12.27 5.4,15.36 10.55,20.03L12,21.35L13.45,20.03C18.6,15.36 22,12.27 22,8.5C22,5.41 19.58,3 16.5,3Z" />
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="card__img">
                <img src="{{recipe.image.url}}">
            </div>
            <a href="{% url 'recipe_view' recipe.id %}" class="card_link">
                <div class="card__img--hover"></div>
            </a>
            <div class="card__info">
                <span class="card__category">{{ recipe.category }}</span>
                <h3 class="card__title">{{ recipe.title }}</h3>
                <span class="card__by">by <a href="#" class="card__author" title="author">{{ recipe.user }}</a></span>
            </div>
        </article>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </section>
```

In the original design the image url was called from the CSS, like so:

```
.card--1 .card__img,
.card--1 .card__img--hover {
    background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/45202/brownie-dessert-cake-sweet-45202.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260');
}
```

In the browser's developer tools, the image is correctly linked.
[image of dev tool code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEqVV.png)

Any ideas?

Show the image from the recipe class

Answer (score -1):

The HTML-`img`tag requires the `alt` argument to be valid. If invalid your browser will refuse to display it. In case the user has weird browser settings that do not allow images to display or for some reason the images can not be loaded properly the text of the `alt` argument is displayed as **alt**ernative. It should be a short, precise representation of the image's content.

This is valid:

```html
<img src="{{ recipe.image.url }}" alt="yummy food">
```

This (your version) is not valid:

```html
<img src="{{recipe.image.url}}">
```

Comment: This is not true. `alt` is not _required_.